# popen sending command to

Tags: python, linux, operating-system, popen

I am trying to open a program Y from a program X, and continue working with program X, however, it seems that once the Y was called using the command line, it starts skipping whatever is next in the code, while still responding to keystrokes.

So the question is, how would one allow X finish the code.

I use:

```
 proc=subprocess.Popen([cmd], shell=True)
 proc.communicate()
```

as well as:

```
 os.system([cmd])
```

where cmd is the command for the terminal with arguments.

I'm runnin Linux by the way.

Comment: I'm confused: first you say that Y is called by X (i.e. programmatically), then you mention calling it from the command line. Did you really mean "X"?

Answer (score 0):

Both ways (`Popen`+`communicate()` and `os.system`) are *synchronous*, therefore the execution of the parent process blocks until the child is finished.

If you want to have both processes running concurrently, you have to come up with a different way to collect output from the child.

A few ideas:

1. Move the code inside a thread in the parent process (see [threading](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html))
2. Strip out `proc.communicate()` and collect the child output in a different way than [stdout pipes](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate). See the [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) module for more ideas. Or, if you feel brave, take a look at [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/) (might be overkill, mind you, I just think it's a great communication library).

Comment: hey, i just figured that I am supposed to use 2.4 compiler version only, considering that, do you think those ways you mentioned would still work?

Comment: Wow! Version 2.4 is really outdated (almost 4 years old). The `multiprocessing` module was introduced in 2.6. As for ZeroMQ I don't know, but I don't think it really suits your case. The `threading` module might be your best bet.